# About the cardinality of natural numbers [Solved]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, philosophy

I had learned that the set is countable if and only if it is finite or countably infinite. We know well that the set $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ is an infinite set. In order to find out if the finite set $X$ is countable, we have to check if there exists an injection $f:X\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $|X|\leq |\mathbb{N}|$. If there is an bijection $f:X\to\mathbb{N}$, then $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$ and the set $X$ is countably infinite.

**Question**: Is $\mathbb{N}$ defined to be countable, or has it ever been proven to be countable?

<s>**Edit**: I know that there's  a bijection from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, and then $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|$. But this doesn't really answer my question. What if it were $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ instead? I just want to know where the idea come from to decide that $\mathbb{N}$ is countable. And then we talk about other sets, like $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Have the mathematicians chosen that the $\mathbb{N}$ is defined to be countable? I can not find any sources that explain about it. Many definitions about the countable set is including the "countable" set $\mathbb{N}$, for example, a set $X$ is countable if and only if $X\leq \mathbb{N}$.</s>

**Edit**: I was really bad at expressing what I meant. I'll write down short how I found the "answer". In reality, I misunderstood definition completely that made me question something rubbish. The definition is

> A set $X$ is countable, if and only if $|X|\leq \mathbb{N}$.

This doesn't say anything about $\mathbb{N}$ (which is what the question was about), but only about $X$. If letting $X=\mathbb{N}$ and that there's an injection from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$ would imply that the set $X$ is countable. That's it.

Comment: Can you think of a bijection from $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @BenS. Oh, never thought about it until now. Thanks!

Comment: @BenS. If there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, then $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|$, but how is it decided that the set $\mathbb{N}$ is countable? What if there is a  bijection from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$? I know well that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable if I accepted that $\mathbb{N}$ is countable. I just want to know why $\mathbb{N}$ is countable to begin with, or where this idea come from.

Comment: I think that usually people define something to be countable if it has the same cardinality as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (which is what you have written above). One of the motivations behind calling $\mathbb{N}$ or a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is that you can hope to label the elements (if you have an infinite amount of time): 1,2,3,4,.... For something like $\mathbb{R}$, you can't ever hope to do that: For any number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ which we assign the label $1$, we have such a huge amount of numbers between $x$ and any other numbers, that there is no hope of doing any counting!

Comment: One of the most surprising things is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable but $\mathbb{R}$ is not...you can read about that sort of thing here for example: [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite)

Comment: The set of all natural numbers is defined to be countable. The concept of countability is, when $A$ is countable, we can label the elements of $A$ as   a number and can count them; We observe that we have used the natural numbers when enumerating and numbering something.

Comment: Instead of using [Solved] tag in the title, accept an answer. If no answer satisfies you (but you have an answer), post your own answer, and then accept it when you can (there is a time limitation on accepting self-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Countably infinite sets are "the same size as" $\Bbb{N}$, which means that there's a bijection (a one-to-one correspondence) between them and the natural numbers.  The identity function $\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ is, of course, a bijection, showing that the set of natural numbers is countably infinite.

Cardinality ("size") of a set is a type of [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on sets:  two sets are equivalent if they have the same cardinality.  The *reflexive* property is what your question is about.  It's worth trying to prove the other two properties:  *symmetry* and *transitivity*.

Answer (score 0):

Countable infinite is just the "firsth class of infinity", and the collection of natural numbers is the prototype example. Need for uncountable sets was the proper theory of real numbers, i.e. the point set theoretical understanding of a geometrical line. Cardinality is just a method to classify different sizes of sets since due to Cantor's diagonal argument there are different types of infinities.

After that mathematicians started to do what they usually do: they go axiomatics.